# align list items vertically inside a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How do you veritcally align list items inside a CSS grid?

Doing vertical align middle does not seem to do anything. Why does vertical align middle not work inside the CSS grid?

Below is the first attempt:

```css
.sublist-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.list-grid {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.list-grid li {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 230px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sublist-grid" style="left: -250px;display: grid;">
<ul class="list-grid">
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to have the items on the left (that are only one line) to align in the middle with the items that are longer.

I found:

[Vertical align inside css grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236101/vertical-align-inside-css-grid)

```css
.sublist-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.list-grid {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.list-grid li {
    /*Answer suggests flex on parent, flex 1 on child*/
    display: flex;

    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 230px;
    text-transform: none;
}

.list-grid li a {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sublist-grid" style="left: -250px;display: grid;">
<ul class="list-grid">
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Essentially (as far as I understand) this answer suggests to add flex and give `flex: 1` to the child but that doesn't work.

[How to vertically align objects in CSS when working with CSS grids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562613/how-to-vertically-align-objects-in-css-when-working-with-css-grids)

An answer with 5 upvotes (accepted answer only has 2) simply suggests to add `align-items: center;` but it does not work:

```css
.sublist-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.list-grid {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.list-grid li {
   /*does not work*/
    align-items: center;

    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 230px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sublist-grid" style="left: -250px;display: grid;">
<ul class="list-grid">
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Why do none of these answers work with my code? How do I get items vertically centered in a CSS grid?

Answer (score 2):

`align-items` **does** work but you have to place it on the **grid-parent / container**

```css
.sublist-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.list-grid {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
   /*does  work*/
    align-items: center;
}

.list-grid li {


    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 230px;
    text-transform: none;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="sublist-grid" style="left: -250px;display: grid;">
<ul class="list-grid">
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it:

It's:

```
.list-grid li {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

So:

```css
.sublist-grid {
    display: grid;
}

.list-grid {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.list-grid li {
    /*this is it*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    list-style-position: inside;
    width: 230px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sublist-grid" style="left: -250px;display: grid;">
<ul class="list-grid">
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList itemList itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="">List itemList itemList item</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```